# Mongo subfield dot notation containing special characters

Tags: database, mongodb

If I have the following object:

```
{
  someMapping: {
     "some key with spaces & special characters": true,
     "simple_key": true
  }
}
```

How can I find this document using the dot notation query? In other words, how can I use `$exists` (which doesn't seem to play well without dot notation) to find it?

I tried:

```
> db.mycol.findOne({ someMapping: { "some key with spaces & special characters": { $exists: true } } })
null
> db.mycol.findOne({ someMapping: { simple_key: { $exists: true } } })
null
> db.mycol.findOne({ "someMapping['some key with spaces & special characters']": { $exists: true } })
null
> db.mycol.findOne({ "someMapping.simple_key": { $exists: true } })
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work

```
db.mycol.findOne({ "someMapping.some key with spaces & special characters": 
    { $exists: true } })
```

More information at [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

```
db.mycol.findOne({ "someMapping.some key with spaces & special characters": true })
```

Edit:
Mongodb [does not support dot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) and dollar sign in field name

Note: $exists returns `true` if field exists. If you want to compare field value to true just run

Comment: What if the key contains `.`?

Comment: mongodb does not support dot. Answer updated with the link